# Laplace transform in the Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, integral-transforms, dispersive-pde

Given the Fokker-Planck equation
$$D\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\rho(x;t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\rho(x;t)$$
the paper I'm reading said to have taken the Laplace transform, resulting
$$D\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\rho(x;s)=s\rho(x;s)-\rho(x;0)$$
I just can't get this result.

> Maybe I don't understand what the author meant by the notation "$;t$", because it seems that $t$ is a given constant, but if I assume so the transform results: $$\frac{1}{s}D\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\rho(x;s)=sL[\rho(x;t)]-\rho(x;0)=s\frac{\rho(x;s)}{s}-\rho(x;0)$$
>   If this is right the result should be $$D\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\rho(x;s)=s(\rho(x;s)-\rho(x;0))$$
>   Is it a typing error or I missed something?

Comment: You can get to the below answer just by directly using the definition of Laplace transform and integration by parts. Though the identity used is common in lower levels courses​ on the subject of ODEs

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathcal{L}(s)\{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\rho(x,t)\}=s\mathcal{L}(s)\{\rho(x,t)\}-\rho(x,0)=s\rho(x,s)-\rho(x,0)\\
\mathcal{L}(s)\{D{\partial^2 \over \partial x^2} \rho(x,t)\}=D{\partial^2 \over \partial x^2}\mathcal{L}(s)\{ \rho(x,t)\}=D{\partial^2 \over \partial x^2}\rho(x,s)$$

Please note how the notation is overloaded into $\rho$.

Comment: Why is the Laplace tranform of rho(x,t) simply rho(x,s)?

Comment: the notation is overloaded, this is common. Normally you write the laplace transform of r as R. There is no capital rho in mathjax so........